# Using Process Runtime Exec To Run A Batch File With "Start"

Tags: java, process, exec, runtime.exec

I'd like to run a Windows batch file via Java's Runtime::exec method. Inside my batch file, I execute another batch file to run a Java program. This first batch file uses "start" to execute the second batch file.

I want my main thread, the one which calls Runtime::exec, to wait ONLY until the first batch file completes, but not to care about the second batch file. I am consuming everything from Process::getInputStream() and Process::getErrorStream(), in 2 separate threads. My main thread (the one that executes Runtime::exec) waits until the 2 stream consuming threads finish, before continuing.

However, I am finding that my main thread always blocks until the second batch file has completed, because even after the first batch file finishes executing, my stream consuming threads continue to read. How do I get them to ignore the output and error streams from the 2nd batch file?

This is how I execute the first batch file, in my main thread:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] cmd = new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "batch1.bat"};
Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);
StreamLogger errorLogger = new StreamLogger(proc.getErrorStream()); // consume
StreamLogger outputLogger = new StreamLogger(proc.getInputStream()); // consume
errorLogger.start(); // start reading the error stream in another thread
outputLogger.start(); // start reading the output stream in another thread
returnCode = proc.waitFor();
log.debug("Obtained return code");
errorLogger.join();
outputLogger.join();
log.debug("Finished reading from streams");
```

batch1.bat looks like this:

```
start "" batch2.bat
exit
```

In batch2.bat, I run a java program (I have tried running it with both java.exe or javaw.exe)

```
javaw.exe -cp . MyProgram 1>outlog 2>errlog
```

In summary, when I run my main thread, I can obtain the return code once batch1.bat finishes (i.e. waitFor() unblocks), but the main thread blocks until batch2.bat and the javaw.exe have terminated, because of "errorLogger.join()" and "outputLogger.join()". I am not interested in reading the output from batch2.bat; how do I get my main thread to return once batch1.bat finishes?

Answer (score 0):

That is bound to happen, when you use the `waitFor` method, if `batch2.bat` runs on the same process as `batch1.bat`.

Out of the top of my head, I'd say you have a couple of options (If you really want to wait for the first batch file to finish executing):

1. Use a script which is capable of invoking an independent process for batch2.bat.
2. Send a marker to the `outputlogger` which tells your parent process that `batch1.bat` has finished executing and don't use `waitFor`. This will help you continue with your code logic.

Comment: Thank you for answering, actually, my code does not block at the waitFor method after batch1.bat completes, it is blocking at "errorLogger.join()" and "outputLogger.join()" until batch2.bat completes.

Comment: try `start cmd /c batch2.bat` in your batch1.bat. Also, does the log have this line `"Obtained return code"`, in your latest run ( when your code blocks at `errorLogger.join()`)?

Comment: Thanks, I tried `start cmd /c batch2.bat`, but got the same results; my log shows `"Obtained return code"` after batch1 completes, and my code still blocks at errorLogger.join() until batch2 terminates.

Comment: Well, the way I see it happening, is that your stream does not return an `EOF` until the `batch2.bat` completes. Hence, the `join()` method holds your main thread until the `errorlogger` and `outputlogger` threads are done executing. This just means that the stream is collecting data from one process `batch1.bat` which does not end until `batch2.bat` is done. So, you'll have to figure out how to invoke a new process from the script, or not use `join()` at all.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I will not use join() after all

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling your second batch via start /b batch2.bat?

Comment: No, I will try that out and post the results here